# Unit test with Microsoft.Office.Interop dll fails on build server

Tags: c#, excel, com, ms-office

I've written a unit test. The code under test references Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll.

The test runs fine on my machine but fails on the build server. It fails on the line where the Excel application is instantiated:

```
var application = new Application { Visible = Visible };
```

The error is:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error:
80040154 Class not registered
```

Does this mean I have to install the Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies on my build server? And if so, do I also need to install Excel on the build server?

**Edit:**
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll is included in my solution and it is referenced from there.

Comment: If your test needs the assembly to be present, then clearly it needs to be on the machine where the test is running. Or are you asking something else? You may be able to get away with registering the single DLL on that machine, and not have to install Excel.  Check that DLL's dependencies with the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: I'm fairly sure you are going to have to install Office on your build server for this to work.

Comment: @Peter thanks, I have edited my answer to clarify. I already tried registering the dll but I got "DllRegisterServer entry point was not found. This file can nto be registered" just like this guy: http://serverfault.com/questions/59431/regsvr32-error-dllregisterserver-entry-point-was-not-found

Comment: You *must* install Office on that machine.  Do *not* try to register anything, you didn't write a COM server, just a COM client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install Office and the Primary Interop Assemblies for that version, or Visual Studio to get this to work. You might run into COM issues with running in a CI environment, and if you can restructure your tests to avoid using Office Interop, I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: Bonus: If you're testing with Office 2007 on a x64 Server 2008 box, get ready to hack the registry to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying I will need to install ((Office && PIA) || Visual Studio) or (Office && (PIA || Visual Studio))? :-)

Comment: Visual Studio installs the PIA assemblies as part of the 'Office developer tools'. In VS2010, those include both 2007 and 2010 PIA assemblies in this ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12' or 'Office14') folder. If you install Office (2k7, or 2k10) you can install them by enabling '.Net Programmability Support. The third option, is to install Office, and the the PIA redist. The third option is useful if you've installed Office, and just want to run a simple setup instead of running the Office installer in 'Change' mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to the solution in a library folder and reference the assembly there the build machine should get the required assembly when you promote.  Otherwise, you're referencing an assembly that comes with the installation of Excel.  Also, if you try to distribute your application without putting it in the solution anyone who tries to run your application that doesn't have Excel installed will get run time errors.

Or course, you're other option if you do not want to redistribute the assembly is to put a try/catch around the code that calls the Excel assembly and then display a message to the user saying an installation of Excel is required.

Finally, each version of Excel (2010, 2007, etc) has different version numbers.  Meaning, if you're using the 2010 assembly and someone has 2007 Excel installed they will get run time errors.  The answer I ended up using for that was reflection to pick which assembly is used in their environment.

Comment: Hi Marcus. Thanks, yes I already have the .dll in a solution folder and it is referenced from there. I will update the question to clarify.

Comment: Are you running any type of script to register the assembly on the build machine?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it looks like you need to [install the PIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> The primary interop assemblies for Microsoft Office products are also available in a redistributable Microsoft Windows Installer package:
>
> The package for Microsoft Office 2003 is available for download from the Microsoft Download Center (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=50479).
>
> The package for the 2007 Microsoft Office system is available for download from the Microsoft Download Center (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=72637).

And, for completeness, the Office 2010 package is here: (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3508)