# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis, dll

I have web-site that uses MS Excel files read/write.

I added related dll's to Bin folder of the site, and it works perfect on my local host (I think bacause I have installed MS Excel 2010 on my pc)

But when I uploaded it to remote pc and run the site, it throws an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

files in Bin folder are:

```
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll 
office.dll 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xml 
office.xml
```

I've installed on remote pc "Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable",
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

But same error ocurrs.

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the complete error description?

Comment: you need to install office 2010 to make this work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762506/unit-test-with-microsoft-office-interop-dll-fails-on-build-server read this post.

Comment: Kiran1016, please write your comment as answer to my question, to mark it as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way - Install MS Office (MS Excel)

Comment: To install Excel on a web server in order to get a assembly file is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this thread is a little bit old but I had the same error and I solved it (it works in my project).

In my web.config file I had assemblies added:

`<add assembly="office, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"/>` and many other office assemblies.

The thing I have done is that I have removed all the assemblies from web.config file and had added dlls as a reference - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll in this case.

I am not an expert and I just thinking loudly that web.config file is trying to pull dll. file from C:\Windows\assembly\ and if there if it could not be foud, returns error.

You don't have to install office or other unneccessary stuff on you server.

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Correct procedure to use Excel in C# Projects is:

1. Add reference to Excel Interop Library(Assembly)
2. Add Excel in `using` section
3. Now use it in your coding.

---

---

The first step will work if you have Office(Excel) Installed in your PC. If not then install. Then add reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` of the version you need.

a. If list doesn't shows the desire version then you may have another vision of Office with Excel installed. By The Way, you can use any.

b. If you don't find anything like `Microsoft.Office.Interop` THEN may be office not installed OR you have Office 2013 or later. For higher version you can add assembly by going into **COM** tab of add-reference windows and add `Microsoft Excel {version-no} Object Library`. This will add the same.

c. If you already have `Microsoft.Office.Interop...` in References with yellow-triangle-mark THEN remove it first.

---

---

After that second step will totally work: `using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

---

---

And finally as a third step you can create Excel object by `Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();`.

Answer (score 0):

you no need to install MS Office- 2010, 
Add Reference -> COM-> "Microsoft office 12.0 Object Libaray"

its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you run application throught IIS , you need to set Identity as Local System.

[image]