# "Could not load file or assembly" while trying to access Excel with vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-interop

I am trying to get Data from an Excel File with vb.net.
I am using VS2019, Excel 2019 and the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.
When I try to run my code I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x80070002   Nachricht =
> Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.

This is how I try to access Excel:

```
Dim excelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim excelLength As Integer
```

While I did not find anything specific to my situation it looks like the problem might stem from a incompatible version, but I'm not sure if it is my version of Excel or the COM-Object I'm using.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527305/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-office-interop-excel-version-14-0-0

Comment: Depending on what your doing, might find it more reliable to use oledb or one of the may prebuilt excel libraries rather than relying on office interops