# How to reference non-existant Office libraries when running MSBuild on a build server

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, office-interop

I am trying to set up .Net builds on our Hudson (CI build) server. One application uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll. This is not found on the build server and causes the build to fail.

I obviously don't want to install Office on the server just for this case so what do I do?

To clarify: this is a build server. The project is not run on the server and Excel is not needed except to satisfy the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Install the primary interop assemblies:

- Office 2003: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20923
- Office 2007: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346
- Office 2010: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Those PIA's should be also deployed to the GAC when you install Visual Studio (if you can).

You might also take a look at this question: [Unit test with Microsoft.Office.Interop dll fails on build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762506/unit-test-with-microsoft-office-interop-dll-fails-on-build-server)

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, the PIAs do require that Office is installed first which is really what I would like to avoid.

Comment: It should also work with having Visual Studio (or at least VSTO) installed ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward if you are using nuget and any repositories like nexus for dependency management. In our project we use VS2017 which has msbuild nicely integrated with nuget and it does the job to download this dll locally and on build server.

Hope this helps